# remove duplicate item using index

Tags: vb.net

I have text file which contains the following:

```
"hello", "say hello"
"hello", "say hi"
"hi", "say hi"
"hi", "good morning"
```

I want to check only the first value of each pair for duplicates and remove the pair if a duplicate is found.

I want this result from the previous set of pairs:

```
"hello", "say hello"
"hi", "say hi"
```

I tried the use the following code but the result is not what I want.

```
 Dim SR As New StreamReader("file.txt")
    Dim MyArray As New List(Of string)
    Dim strLine() As String
    Do While SR.Peek <> -1
        strLine = SR.ReadLine().Split(","c)      
        If MyArray.Contains(strLine(0)) = False Then
            MyArray.Add(strLine(0) & "," & strline(1))
        End If
    Loop
```

If anyone could enlighten me it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you need this in C#, or what is the tag for?

Comment: Why did you tag c# if you are using VB.NET?

Comment: c# or vb.net is both ok for me

Comment: `but result is not what i want` Are we to read your mind to know how that doesnt work or  what you *do* want?

Comment: `Dim MyArray As New List(Of string)` you notice yourself?

Comment: yes if you can read my mind lol

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with LINQ:

```
Dim distinctByFirstColumn = From line In File.ReadLines("file.txt")
                            Let fields = line.Split(","c)
                            Let firstField = fields(0).Trim()
                            Group line by firstField Into firstFieldGroup = Group
                            Select firstFieldGroup.First() ' you want first line of duplicates
```

If you want to rewrite the file:

```
File.WriteAllLines("file.txt", distinctByFirstColumn.ToList())
```

But i hope thise fields never contain commas itself. You should really use a csv parser that suppports quoting characters instead like the [`TextFieldParser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx).